# How to use a string variable from another class

Tags: java, sqlite

I would like to access a string variable from another class to put it into an SQlite DB but I get an error "cannot be resolved or not a field
Here is the code
timestamp.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;




import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

   public class timestamp {



public static String doSomething() throws IOException {     


    File source = new File("C:/Users/India/Desktop/Test/Sub/Test.docx");



    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss-ms");

    String ts=sdf.format(source.lastModified());
    System.out.print(ts);
    //String[] TimeStamp = source.lastModified().toString();

    String name = source.getName();
    String ext = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf("."));
    name = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));
    String outFileName = name + " " + ts + ext;
    //System.out.println(" new file name is " + outFileName);

    File destination = new File("C:/Users/India/Desktop/Test", outFileName);

    FileUtils.copyFile(source,destination);
    return ts;  
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    { doSomething();}}
```

SQLiteJDBC.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

    public class SQLiteJDBC{ 

 public static void InsertValues( String args[] ) throws IOException 
    { timestamp t = new timestamp();
     String var = t.ts;

     System.out.println(t.ts);
     Connection c = null;
Statement stmt = null;
try {
  Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
  c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
  c.setAutoCommit(false);
  System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

  stmt = c.createStatement();
  PreparedStatement prep1 = c.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO ACTIONLOG VALUES (?,?, ?);") ;
  prep1.setString(1, var);

  prep1.addBatch();


  c.setAutoCommit(false);
  prep1.executeBatch();

  c.setAutoCommit(true);



  stmt.close();
  c.commit();
  c.close();
} catch ( Exception e ) {
  System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
  System.exit(0);
}
System.out.println("Records created successfully");
 }


    public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
    { InsertValues(args);
     }
     }
```

I am not able to access the ts string in the database class. I either get a NULL value or an error.
Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: create ts as a global variable then access

Comment: Define String ts; after class name then access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since You are Trying to Access Local Variable from Another Class. better then that go ahead with global variable.update code like that only one line define after class

```
public class timestamp {
 String ts;// Define Here (global variable )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an accessor method within the class and change 'ts' to a global variable. This way, when you instatiate this class, you can simply retrieve it using something like:

```
MyClass.getStringName();
```

where 'getStringName()' is something like:

```
public String getStringName()
{
    return ts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your variables are in class methods, not in class area.
In Class add variable String, not in class method.